# Print only a specific part of a string

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp program(using scriplets) that generates the output in a string.

My JSP Code:

```
<HTML>
-------
-------
<%
-------
-------
a=new String(tmp, 0, i);
out.println(a);
-------
-------
%>
-------
</HTML>
```

Here I am getting the output successfully. But there is a lot of unnecessary data that I get along with it. My jsp shows the output like:

Values: XXXXXX Location: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX....

I want to print only the Values part of the string. I want to omit everything that starts from "Location: XXXXXXXXX" onwards. It always gives me an output in this format.

Is there any way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sample code provided does not print `Values` nor `Location`.  Are you sure this is a correct sample code for the issue you are having? - In other words, what is `tmp` and `i`? where do they come from? how are they initialized?

Comment: If u know that there is always a space after Values : XXXX and before Location, look for indexOf of space and print it. something like 
a = a.substring(0,a.indexOf(" ")); But my advice is to stop using scriptlets and do these things in ur servlet/controller and then print it using EL

Comment: @ochi Thanks for the instant reply. I can give more details in the code, but I felt that would just complicate it even more. I already have the code working and all. So kindly ignore the tmp and i. All I wanted to know is; Now that I have a output string, I want to print only a part of it. Is that even possible?

Comment: @Pranav Yes... you can print a part of it using `substring()` and `indexOf()`

Comment: @Arkantos Thanks for the reply. I shall try and let you know if that works. 

P.S. I have tried using servlets too. But I have faced some issues with it. I tried this with scriplets and it worked. I'll be working on those servlets again, but for now I needed this info. Thanks.

Comment: @ochi Thanks. Will try and let you know.

Comment: just guessing that you're not able to print the values using EL that you've added to request/sessions/application scope in your servlet before forwarding to JSP, if that is the case set the isELIgnored attribute to false in page directive like this

<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %> and u can access any value set in servlet like this ${formattedString}

Comment: @ochi I tried using the substring and indexOf, but I'm not getting any output at all. The jsp page goes blank. 

Should I import anything for this to work?

Comment: @Arkantos That was not the issue I faced. I'm actually a beginner in programming, so my issues were more basic. Still have some studying to do. Thanks.

For the above solution you mentioned, I tried using the substring and indexOf, but I'm not getting any output at all. The jsp page goes blank. Should I import anything for this to work?

Comment: no, string is in  lang package. u don't have to import anything. oops my bad.. i didn't see that there's a space after Values: as well, but aryn's solution should work.

Comment: @Pranav check the tomcat's console (or your server's) to see what (if any) errors you are getting... Sounds like a typo, null pointer exception or something similar is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're asking how to get part of String; this really doesn't have anything to do with JSP.

To only get first part of the string up to "Location:", you want to use the  substring method:

```
out.println(a.substring(0, a.indexOf("Location:"));
```

This says, 'give me a part of the string starting at 0 (the first character) up to (but not including) the first index of "Location:" in the string'.

Comment: I tried using this, but I'm not getting any output at all. The jsp page goes blank. 

Should I import anything for this to work?

Comment: @Pranav No, the String class is in the lang package. You shouldn't need any imports for that. We need some more information about the code around the println statement to help any further - if the "a" variable was truly like "Values: XXXXXX Location: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", that code snippet should work.